# How Find what procedures doing Insert or Update particular table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have more than 500 procedures.

I want to add a column to the table `[tstdata]`. I will need to update all the procedures doing insert or update that use the table `[tstdata]`.

So how to find these procedures in an easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sp_depends` to find all dependent objects like following

```
sp_depends TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to search for the contents of procs/functions:

```
select o.id,o.name,c.text from syscomments c inner join sysobjects o on o.id = c.id
```

The text property is what you need to search.  This would be the equivalent of using ALL_SOURCE and ALL_OBJECTS in Oracle.